# Objective c xpath query not working

Tags: ios, xpath

I'm trying to get the content out of

```
<p>
    <strong>Some headline</strong>
    Some text here ...
</p>
```

I want to store the `"some text here ..."` in a `NSString`.
My XPath query looks like this

```
@"//div[@class='articleInfo']/div[@class='readMore description']/div[@class='readMoreContent']/p"
```

but that is returning `null`.

Please help!

Comment: Can you post full html contents? or atleast till <p> - It would help us to analyse XPath query which relies on child and parent elements.

Comment: There is a couple of divs

<div class="readMoreContent">

    <p>
         <strong>Some headline</strong>
         Some text here ...
    </p>
</div>

Comment: I don't see any syntactical error in your query. If the hierarchy is same as your query string then it should work. But since you are getting null. It could be 1. Hierarchy level which you might missed 2. Be cautious about element name Ex: @"//div[@class='articleInfo']" is not same as @"//div[@class=' articleInfo']" (Space at the beginning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have something like this:

```
<div class="articleInfo">
<div class="readMore description">
<div class="readMoreContent"> 
<p> 
    <strong>Some headline</strong> 
    Some text here ... 
</p> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

then yours xpath should work:

```
//div[@class='articleInfo']/div[@class='readMore description']/div[@class='readMoreContent']/p/text()
```

Also as @San said, can be typo. I see you have space here "readMore description", but not here "readMoreContent"